# Excel - Getting the address of a value when they are in different places

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Example table]

To search for a value address, I have a table attached to the question with values.
The values are set at H11, J11, M11, P11 and S11.

The catch is that locations are fixed but values are shuffled at the same address, which means J11 value might to go to H11 or P11 to J11, and so on.

I see I can get the address if they're side by side, but I can't figure out when they're in different cells like the example I have attached.

I appreciate if you can help me with the possible formulas

Comment: May be something like this can work: `=ADDRESS(11,MATCH(B12,$11:$11,0))` or `=ADDRESS(ROW($11:$11),MATCH(B12,$11:$11,0))`

Comment: It may be useful to know what it is you are trying to accomplish. What is it you want the address for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by OP that worked for them, hence posted in answers.

[image]

---

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D12`

```
=ADDRESS(11,MATCH(B12,$11:$11,0))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C12`

```
=ADDRESS(ROW($11:$11),MATCH(B12,$11:$11,0))
```

---